# Sequential Number of URL

Tags: drupal, joomla, web

Just a quick question. I am trying to help a friend with his website. I have dabbled in web development a bit, and am trying to help him save him a little money. Anyways, enough of that.

On his site, he wants users to be able to sign up and create a profile. This profile will store certain information about the user. Is it possible to allow users to sign up and their profile page will be given a sequential number for the url. I know this isn't very clear, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to word this, I think.

Basically, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

User1 signs up for a profile on this site. His profile url would be http://www.mywebsite.com/1

Now, a new user signs up and their URL would be http://www.mywebsite.com/2.

All the profiles would be an increasing sequential number. Rather than coding the bulk of the website from scrath, I have considered trying to accomplish this, using Drupal or Joomla. Is there a way to get this done? I would really appreciate any help that you folks could offer. I will be checking this fairly often, so if you need any more information, just let me know. Thanks again and in advance. Take care all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal will do this out of the box.  And you can use the pathauto module to rewrite the url of profiles to whatever scheme you want.

Comment: Thanks, jakraska. I was hoping it would be something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your database such that when every user signs up, it would generate the ID automatically sequencially. You can do this just by setting the **id** field as **autonumber**.

Then, use URL rewrite to cloak the requests that are coming. E.g. in apache, using **.htaccess** you can setup the server such that **http://www.example.com/users/1/** gets processed as **http://www.example.com/profile.php?id=1**.

I am not sure of the exact syntax, but that is available on loads of websites around the web.

Best of Luck.